How to solve ERROR 1064 (42000) when migrating from XAMPP to Laragon?
I'm using XAMPP 3.3.0, Laragon 6.0
I'm following Migrate From XAMPP and I'm up to the last part. When I run:
mysql -u root -p < C:\laragon\tmp\alldb.sql
It gives this error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 72: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 TRANSACTIONA' at line 14
The part where it has the error is this:
CREATE TABLE `column_stats` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `column_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `min_value` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_value` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nulls_ratio` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_length` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_frequency` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hist_size` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `hist_type` enum('SINGLE_PREC_HB','DOUBLE_PREC_HB') DEFAULT NULL,
  `histogram` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`)
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 TRANSACTIONAL=0 COMMENT='Statistics on Columns';

The 'Statistics on Columns' part is correct. I tried to use backticks, single quotes, and double quotes but it's still giving the same error.

Laragon-6.0.0 is MySQL-8.0.30. ref. Honestly it doesn't look like a currently maintained project. The "manual corresponding to your MySQL server version" is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html .

Do not migrate anything in these DATABASEs: mysql, information_schema, performance_schema.  `Aria exists only in MariaDB, not MySQL.
